# Tailwind how to a fix sidebar?

Tags: tailwind-css

i am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOOoS6GHDw8) by chris sev on Better Dev channel.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/chris__sev/pen/RwKWXpJ) for the tutorial.

I want to make this sidebar fixed and avoid scrolling. Right now if i put content the sidebar also scrolls with the content.

i have tried `fixed top-0` and `sticky top-0`on the div with the `sidebar` class.

None of this seemed to do it. Anyone know how to make the side bar fixed?

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/x23AbgvIWu -- replace `md:relative` by `md:fixed`

Answer (score 3):

the main problem of your example was the wrong usage of flex and how you implemented it.

Here's a clean version of your [codepen](https://codepen.io/fabiencrapetto/pen/NWvjoxo) link (without the mobile version, I'll let you deal with that ;)

In short, you need to make sure the FLEX main app will use the full window size :

```
<div id="app" class="fixed flex w-full h-full ...">
```

Once the main app is set, you will just need to adapt the children to your needs :

```
<div id="sidebar" class="w-64 ...">
```

As you can see, you just need to set the width for the "static" element (the one that needs to stay always the same)
The dynamic element – the content container – will have more flexibility, therefore we apply `.flex-1` :

```
  <div id="content" class="flex-1 overflow-auto ...">
```

This is not really related to tailwind but rather to `display: flex;` itself.

(PS : I've edited so you only see the important classes)